# pandas isin() fail between dataframes with objects types columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, isin

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: a=pd.DataFrame([1,2,'a'])

In [2]: a.isin([1,'a'])
Out[2]:
       0
0   True
1  False
2   True

In [3]: a.isin(pd.DataFrame([1,'a']))
Out[3]:
       0
0   True
1  False
2  False
```

why isin cant find 'a' in a DataFrame but can in a list?.

PS: Using pandas 1.0.5

In [4]: pd.**version**
Out[4]: '1.0.5'

Answer (score 3):

The [`pd.DataFrame.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) docs spell out this behavior pretty clearly, emphasis my own.

> If values is a DataFrame, then **both the index and column labels must match**.

So looking at your two DataFrames side by side:

```
a   isin  pd.DataFrame([1,'a'])

   0           0
0  1        0  1    True  <- 1 == 1 for col label (0) and index label (0) 
1  2        1  a    False <- 2 != 'a' for col label (0) and index label (1)
2  a                False <- Nothing to align
```

Comment: hey, thanks, and how to ignore indexing to isin between dataframes ?

Comment: @FrancoMilanese You could convert all the values to a single array: `pd.DataFrame([1,'a']).to_numpy().ravel()`